# What is the result set ordering when using window functions that have `order by` components?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, sql-order-by

I'm working on a query on the SEDE:

```
select top 20 
  row_number() over(order by "percentage approved" desc, approved desc), 
  row_number() over(order by "total edits" asc), 
  *
from editors 
where "total edits" > 30
```

**What is the ordering of the result set, taking into account the two window functions?**

I suspect it's undefined but couldn't find a definitive answer.  OTOH, results from queries with one such window function were ordered according to the `over(order by ...)` clause.

Comment: Those `ORDER BY` are "internal" to the windowing functions and are used **solely** to determine the windowing function's values - they have **NO EFFECT** whatsoever on the "outer" SELECT - they do **NOT** specify an `ORDER BY` for the whole SELECT in any way, shape or form

Comment: Order is not guaranteed. However if you **want** a particular ordering then the order you list the columns in the `SELECT` statement [can make a difference to efficiency.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2011/06/06/column-order-can-matter.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s not true that "they have no effect" -- please see the OP for an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The results can be returned in **any** order.

Now, they will often be returned in the same order as specified in the `OVER` clause, but this is just because SQL Server is likely to pick a query plan that sorts the rows to calculate the aggregate. This is by no means guaranteed, as it could pick a different query plan at any time, especially as you make your query more complex which extends the space of possible query plans.

Answer (score 5):

The result set of **ANY** SQL Server query that doesn't have an explicit `ORDER BY` is undefined.

This includes when you have window functions within the query, or an `ORDER BY` in a subquery.  The result order will depend on a lot of factors, none of which are guaranteed unless you specify an `ORDER BY`.